# Entity Framework Core Repository Pattern Eager Load

Tags: c#, sql-server, generics, entity-framework-core

I am trying to build out a web application using a repository pattern. In doing so, I have noticed that my navigation properties are not loading. I was able to get my properties to load using EF Proxies, but when I went to use my DTOs, it really didn't like that. I have since removed all the Proxy bit of code and decided that I just need to provide a way to Eager Load the data I care about.

In my repository, I have an interface similar to this. Using DBSet, I am able to use the Find method to generically find the value and return it from the repo. Doing this, I am not able to pass in Includes to resolve the navigation properties.

```
public async Task<T> GetById(int Id)
        {
            var query = await this.Context.Set<T>().FindAsync(Id);
            // Left split like this for clarity
            return query;
        }
```

The only way I got this working was by removing the generic piece and adding a new method called GetUserById into the UserRepository.

```
    public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly Context _context;
        public UserRepository(Context context) : base(context) {
            _context = context;
        }

        public User GetUserById(int Id)
        {
            var query = _context.Users.Include("Department").Where(x => x.Id == Id).FirstOrDefault();
            return query;
        }
    }
```

Please tell me there is a better way.

Comment: Take a look at [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.UnitOfWork](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#microsoftentityframeworkcoreunitofwork)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `GetUserById` implementation:

```
    public User GetUserById(int Id, params Expression<Func<User, object>>[] includes)
    {
        var query = _context.Users.Where(x => x.Id == Id);

        foreach (var include in includes)
        {
            query.Include(include);
        }

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And this is how you would call it:

```
    var repo = new UserRepository();
    var user = repo.GetUserById(100, u => u.Department);
```

Comment: In theory this would work. I want to keep this general though. If I have several entities, I would like to conditionally include Includes to Eager load the data we care about without having to get a Get<Entity>ById for each entity type.